# spherical polar geometry change in elevation angle

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres, spherical-trigonometry

how to calculate change in elevation angle if you know coordinates of two point on surface of sphere. let us say assume that a point move on the surface of sphere from [x1 y1 z1 ] = [0.1 0.1 0.9899] to [x2 y2 z2] = [-0.1 -0.1 0.9899].

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to define a [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). The term *elevation angle* is used with the definition
$$\bbox{ \vec{p} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix}
r \cos\theta \cos\varphi \\
r \cos\theta \sin\varphi \\
r \sin\theta \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{1}\label{NA1} }$$
where $\varphi$ is the angle on the $xy$ plane, with $0\text{°}$ being on the positive $x$ axis, and $90\text{°}$ on the positive $y$ axis; and $\theta$ being the angle to the $xy$ plane, with $0\text{°}$ referring to the $xy$ plane ($z = 0$), positive angles up to $90\text{°}$ referring to the hemisphere with positive $z$, and negative angles dow to $-90\text{°}$ referring to the hemisphere with negative $z$.  In other words, $\theta$ is the elevation angle.

The inverse of $\eqref{NA1}$ is
$$\bbox{\begin{cases}
r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \\
\varphi = \arctan(y, x) \\
\theta = \arcsin(z / r) \end{cases} \tag{2}\label{NA2}}$$

Thus, if you have a vector $(x, y, z)$, its elevation angle is
$$\bbox{ \theta = \arcsin\left( \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \right) \tag{3}\label{NA3}}$$

If we compare two points, $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$, the change in the elevation angle is
$$\bbox{ \theta_2 - \theta_1 = \arcsin\left( \frac{z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2}} \right) - \arcsin\left( \frac{z_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2}} \right) }\tag{4}\label{NA4}$$
Unfortunately, I do not see any way of simplifying that expression, unless we place some restrictions on the coordinates.

For example, when $z_1 = z_2$, and $x_1^2 + y_1^2 = x_2^2 + y_2^2$, the elevation angle does not change. (Essentially, the points are then on the same *latitude*.)

Therefore, in OP's case, the elevation angle does not change between $(0.1, 0.1, 0.9899)$ and $(-0.1, -0.1, 0.9899)$; it is $81.869\text{°}$, or $1.42889$ radians in both cases.